# Destructoring object during function invoke

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to use a destructoring assigment when invoking a function?

Something like this:

```js
function myFunc(one, two) { ... }

const functionArgs = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
}

myFunc(...functionArgs);
```

Comment: Javascript functions don't have *named arguments*. Arguments are only passed by position, and objects aren't necessarily keeping positions. So… no, not like this.

Comment: What if functionArgs was an array instead? Would that be possible?

Comment: In that case, you'd be spreading the arguments - it's not a destructuring assignment.

Comment: You might want to use an object as params, this works really well with destructuring.

Comment: Be more logical to do `const myFunc = ({one, two}) => {
  console.log(one, two)
};

const functionArgs = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
};

myFunc(functionArgs);`

Comment: Sadly the func is not one if my own APIs, or else I would use those solutions.

Comment: so than you would need to use an array and not an object

Comment: *"Sadly the func is not one if my own APIs,"* if these arguments are such a nuisance to you, don't spread that throughout your code. Use a more convenient adapter: `function notMyFunc(one, two) { ... }` `const myFunc = ({ one, two }) => notMyFunc(one, two);` and then use it `myFunc({ one: 1, two: 2 });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructuring objects won't work but you can spread arrays.

```js
function myFunc(one, two) { 
  console.log(one, two)
 }

const functionArgsObj = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2
}

const functionArgsArr = [
    1,
    2
]


// myFunc(...functionArgsObj); throws error

myFunc(...functionArgsArr); // works as expected (output: 1, 2)
```

Comment: As someone already commented, that's technically a spreader. But I'll take it! Thanks! :)

Comment: Ahh great! I always get confused with the naming of spread and destructuring operator. I think this time I won't forget about it :D